# Java to JSON with cxf JSONProvider

Tags: java, json, cxf

I need to convert my object generated from WSDL file with CXF `cxf-codegen-plugin` to JSON string. I am not lucky to find any solution to that.

As far as I've got is: I've created a Spring config of CXF JSONProvider:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="dropRootElement" value="true"/>
    <property name="dropCollectionWrapperElement" value="false"/>
    <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreNamespaces" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

injected it into my bean and now I am trying to use:

```
try {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    jsonProvider.writeTo(
            evaluationType,
            EvaluationType.class,
            new Annotation[]{},
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
            null,
            new StringOutputStream(writer));

    return writer.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("e", e);
    return "";
}
```

The question is, what kind of annotations I have to provide to this method? There is no documentation about it. I am getting:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.company.test.evaluation.evaluation.EvaluationImpl$1 is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.company.test.evaluation.EvaluationImpl$1
```

This `EvaluationImpl` is the class in which I am calling this method. Please advice what kind of annotations I've to provide to this method. Or maybe there is other ways of doing this using **CXF JSONProvider**?

Comment: JAXB can’t handle non-static inner classes. An easy fix : change your inner class with a concrete one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Jackson [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to convert your java objects to `JSON` there a lot of options for configuring Jackson `ObjectMapper` and it is more easier to use.